# IIS Took Over My Port 80 and I Can't Get it Back! [Windows Server 2008; Trying to run TeamCity]

Tags: iis, iis-7, teamcity, windows-server-2008, web-hosting

**Prologue:** I am running windows Server 2008 R2 on a Virtual Machine. This virtual machine image has been happily hosting TeamCity on port 80 for several weeks. This TeamCity server is accessed by others on the network by visiting a url (pcname.domain.com).

**The Issue:** It seems corporate decided to push some updates to my machine over the weekend. It seems this round of updates decided to install/update IIS. Low and behold, visiting the URL mapped to the TeamCity server actually takes me to the stock IIS7 page. Visiting url/login.html brings me to the TeamCity log-in page.

**Attempts:** First off, I changed the TeamCity port to 8080 and was able to access it at url:8080 (or localhost:8080). However, it is imperative to me that people can access the server without providing a port... so I change TeamCity server port back to 80 and set off to try and fix this IIS problem.

Since then I have uninstalled IIS7 by removing the role and services from Windows - I am now hosting "0 roles". I have removed every trace of IIS from my PC, but visiting localhost still gives me 404 not found (instead of server not found or just my TeamCity page).

**My Question:** How do I prevent Windows Server 2008 from trying to host some default crap on port 80 so that my TeamCity server can be seen again?

**EDIT:** After performing netstat -ano, the only PIDs associated with port 80 are '0' and '4' (system and svchost!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows the usual suspects using port 80 are IIS itself, and maybe the Web Deploy Agent Service if installed (but it could have any other app bound to that port). The PIDs 0 and 4 just tell you that the applciation using that port is running as a service.  If you do not need any of this (IIS, web deploy, etc), go to Services and disable them, the port should be free to bind after that.

You can use `net sh http show servicestate | findstr HTTP` to reach the address and port binding information.

A simple solution (one that I am also using in a production server with multiple apps) is to set up a proxy based on either the domain or the URL path itself ([see here how to with nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)).

Answer (score 0):

Hit command, `netstat -ano` in an elevated command prompt to see what applications are listening on which ports. This command will show you the PID of the process that is listening on port 80. Now, open the Task Manager -> Processes tab. From the View -> Select Columns menu, enable the PID column, and you will see the name of all the processes those are listening on port 80. You can kill the listed tasks. Mostly applications like, World Wide Web Publishing service, IIS Admin Service, Web Deployment Agent Service may use the port 80 in Windows Operating System.